# Rendering helm release values

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am working on helm release which takes it's charts, templates from another GitHub repository for eg. something like this mentioned in a code snippet.
In this scenario how can I test the values rendering using standard helm commands like helm template, helm install etc?

```
apiVersion: helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v2beta1
kind: "HelmRelease"
metadata:
  name: "services"
  namespace: "manual"
  annotations:
    fluxcd.io/automated: "true"
spec:
  interval: 2m
  releaseName: "book-info"
  chart:
    spec:
      **chart: ./backend**
      version: 1.0.1
      sourceRef:
        name: charts
        **kind: GitRepository**
        namespace: flux2
```

What I want to achieve is pass separate values to this helm chart in a file. below is the entire helm release.

I have tried to render values with helm commands

`helm install  mychart-0.1.0.tgz --debug --dry-run services-info.yaml`

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: seems to be a YAML file, but expected a gzipped archive
helm.go:84: [debug] file 'C:\Users\KambliAm\Desktop\Amey\flux-pdtk-dev\pdtk-dev\services-info.yaml' seems to be a YAML file, but expected a gzipped archive
```

Comment: please suggest on this, let me know if I need to clarify the question

Answer (score 1):

just use

```
helm template <CHART_FOLDER> -f your-values.yaml
```

in your case `tar -xf mychart-0.1.0.tgz` will untar chart folder

with this comand you will see rendered chart

to do automated tests see [this](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/chart_tests/)

or just use yq and bash :)

FYI:

helm install -> will deploy chart to k8s
helm template -> render chart without deploy. but you can do

```
helm template CHARTNAME/CHARTFOLDER -f values.yaml > file.yaml && kubectl apply -f file.yaml
```

helm upgrade -> will upgrade already installed chart

see [this](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm/#see-also)

Comment: Thank you this command works like a gem

```
helm template CHARTNAME/CHARTFOLDER -f values.yaml > file.yaml && kubectl apply -f file.yaml
```